# Accessing Enum from Odata

Tags: typescript, odata

I have the following OData.  What I am trying to achieve in Typescript is to use the EnumType  for dropdown list.  I do not seems to able to use http get to access the EnumType BlackLight and Sound.  Is it really possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<edmx:EdmxVersion="4.0"xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices>
<SchemaNamespace="DataService"xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
<EnumType Name="BackLight">
    <MemberName="Level0"Value="0"/>
    <MemberName="Level1"Value="1"/>
    <MemberName="Level2"Value="2"/>
    <MemberName="Level3"Value="3"/>
    <MemberName="Level4"Value="4"/>
    <MemberName="Level5"Value="5"/>
    <MemberName="Level6"Value="6"/>
<MemberName="Level7"Value="7"/>
</EnumType>
<EnumType Name="Sound">
    <MemberName="Level1"Value="1"/>
    <MemberName="Level2"Value="2"/>
    <MemberName="Level3"Value="3"/>
</EnumType>
<ComplexType Name="SystemConfiguration">
    <PropertyName="MeterBackLight"Type="DataService.BackLight"Nullable="false"/>
    <PropertyName="MeterSound"Type="DataService.Sound"Nullable="false"/>
</ComplexType>
<EntityContainer Name="Container">
<EntitySetName="DisplayConfig" EntityType="DataService.SystemConfiguration"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: One way would be to request for the service metadata and then parse the Xml response and extract the enum values. The service metadata endpoint is <ServiceRoot>/$metadata

Comment: Yes, that was the first thought but if you have a large metadata it would be rather very inefficient just to retrieve a few enums.

Comment: AFAIK, OData doesn't support request for partial metadata ATM, e.g. /$metadata/BackLight. One way out, if you maintain the service, would be to add an endpoint that returns back the enum values